# Reading Web pages methods in python and the differences

Tags: python, sockets, request, urllib

There are many different ways of reading web pages in python.

I focused on the following methods:

1. Retrieve a page
2. Opening Socket
3. Making Request

Example of Retrieving a page:

from urllib.request import urlretrieve

```
url = 'http://ce.sharif.edu/courses'
file_name = 'courses.html'

urlretrieve(url, file_name)
```

Example of Opening Socket:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://ce.sharif.edu/courses'
socket = urlopen(url)
text = str(url.readall())

socket.close()
```

Example of Making Request:

```
>>>import requests

>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

So the problem is what are the main differences of the above methods and their usage?

Comment: Do you get different results? Under the hood, those different codes should actually do the same. The difference seems to me to be in the "interface level" only.

Comment: @usr2564301 No, there isn't any different in results. I think it should have a philosophy behind any variety of ways!

Answer (score 0):

The third method is using a different library than the above. This doesn't look like a problem, but let's see the content of the request as seen from the server side.

1)

```
GET /example1.html HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: XXXXXXXX
Connection: close
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.5
```

2)

```
GET /example2.html HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: close
Host: XXXXXXXX
User-Agent: Python-urllib/3.5
```

No noticeable difference between 1) and 2.

3)

```
GET /example3 HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXXX
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4
```

The last is slightly different; this means there is at least the possibility of obtaining different results in the response, and this will depend on the server configuration.

**Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate**
This may result in the server compressing the response, which means less data transferred.

**Connection: keep-alive**
The server will keep the connection open for reusing with subsequent requests (possibly more efficient).

**User-Agent:**
Many web servers adapt the content depending on the identified client software. I don't think there will be any difference in this particular case, however it can't be ruled out completely.